# How to add custom attribute in Collection?

Tags: magento2, order-items

```
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
class Invoice {
 public function getAllItems()
    {
        $items = [];
             foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            if (!$item->isDeleted()) {
                $items[] = $item;
            }
        }
}
  return $filter;
    }
```

This Magento 2 core method. But I want to apply filter in this collection.  As my knowledge this collection from `sales_order_item` table.
I Save custom attribute(`current_seller_id`) in `sales_order_item` table but in this collection my custom attribute is missing and I need to filter collection on the condition of my custom attribute.

Can anyone please help me to tell why my custom attribute is not there and how can I add custom attribute in this collection.

I try

```
  public function getAllItems()
    {
        $items = [];
        $filter=[];
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection()->addFieldToFilter('current_seller_id',array('eq'=>27)) as $item) {
            if (!$item->isDeleted()) {
                $items[] = $item;
            }

       }
return $items;
}
```

But not filter the collection.

Comment: it request please focus on answer instead of edit suggestion

Comment: Your code is from the `Invoice` model. That collection comes from `sales_order_invoice_item`. If your code would be in the `Order` model it would work. Do you want to filter the invoice item collection?

Comment: no am not filter invoice item collection. 
as my knowledge in the New invoice page when click on invoice tap in order view page  a Section "Invoice to item" contain orders items that comes from sales_order_item .

am right ? this collection comes from sales_order_item /

Comment: So the collection you mention comes from order items but not from the code you have pasted in your question. Look at the `getAllItems()` method in the order model, that's the method not in invoice model. If you want to apply the filter to the order item collection only in the invoice creation process please update the question corrsponding and I'll try to give you a solution for that.

Comment: Yes can you guide me how filter the collection that show in New Invoice Page at the Invoice to Item Section show there **https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBNoe.png** 
.
is this screenshort collection comes from sales_order_item table ? i want to filter this collection on the condition on custom attribute in sales_order_item table

Comment: Yes, that items come from order items collection. I've tried to explain you the situation in that context and showed you also an alternative option in my answer below.

Comment: @HaFizUmer Yes as HelgeB mentioned what you've mentioned is invoice class that doesn't have your sales_order_item attribute so below I've given answer for sales_order_item collection to filter by custom attribute, hope that helps you or else do clarify on what you required from this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it needs to said that you cant apply any filter on `getItemsCollection()` in Order model because the collection is already loaded in that method and
after loading filters can't be applied anymore to a collection.

But that shouldn't bother you. You can just iterate through the collection and remove non matching items. For example like this:

```
$filteredItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($filteredItems as $key => $orderItem){
    if ($orderItem->getCurrentSellerId() != 27){
        $filteredItems->removeItemByKey($key);
    }
}
$order->setItems($filteredItems->getItems());
```

You could apply a code like above somewhere appropriate, for example before `Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService::prepareInvoice()` is called.
That's the method which creates new invoices. If you want to use that, you can change the method code below with that and you won't see non matching items.
But you with that approach the totals calculation process may have some difficulties since it's not a good idea to manipulate the order collection in the invoice creation process.

I would suggest you a plugin before the mentioned method, but **I would strongly recommend not to manipulate the order item collection but to work with invoiced quantities**.
That would be exactly the same procedute as you would set quantities into the invoice form and klick `UpdateQty's`, just automatically based on your `current_seller_id`.
You will see all items in the form, but all non matching have qty 0. That would work as follows:

di.xml entry:

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService">
    <plugin name="Module_InvoiceService" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\InvoiceService" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
</type>
```

Vendor/Module/Plugin/InvoiceService.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class InvoiceService{

  public function beforePrepareInvoice(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        array $qtys = []
        )
    {
        foreach ($order->getItemsCollection() as $key => $orderItem){
            if ($orderItem->getCurrentSellerId() == 27){
               $qtys[$orderItem->getId()] = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() - $orderItem->getQtyInvoiced();
            } else {
               $qtys[$orderItem->getId()] = 0;
            }
        }

        return [$order, $qtys];
    }
```

I hope that helps you understand the context and may be a solution for your requirement.

Comment: HelgeB and @Prathap Gunasekaran Thanks for answering me ! my requirement was that i want to filter collection in the new invoice page. I apply condition on the custom attribute (current_seller_id) that is in sales_order_item . . I did this and share with both of you in answer please wait. Thanks for response me ASA

Comment: ! yes it absolute Answer . others thing also manage from your solution,for  example total,grantotal and  current login user entities insert in database.  from my filter getAllItems() it insert all items of invoice and total etc are also count wrong.
Thanks

Comment: HelgeB ! 1 thing more need to correct. In New Invoice page those items which is not for current user is present  in Items to invoice Section with qty,grandtotal,rowtotal etc all thing value are 0. How can we exclude these items which is not belong to current user ?
I want that not  to shown also in New Invoice page. how remove those items ? it should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2HZw.png

Comment: I would not remove them from the collection (because of complications in the calculation process, e.g. for totals) but either not render them in the template (skip the row with qty = 0 or better current_seller_id does not match) or using css class to just hide the row. Just look for the template and see what's the best for you - I guess the template is somewehere in the sales module in adminhtml templates: `order/invoice/create/items/renderer/default.phtml` could be the location

Comment: okay HelgeB ! i try to hide these row from template or css

Comment: HelgeB ! Dear in invoice grid the amount is 0 why this issue create ?  kindly look at this screenshot please   https://screenshots.firefox.com/ePbQ97upXAt2b3Ok/localhost

Comment: What is `Amount` in the grid? In my grid I have `Grand Total`columns but no `Amount` column. What data is in the invoice if you click on view? If you have correct data there (items, subtotal, tax, shipping) the invoice has been created correctly.

Comment: HelgeB Dear In the Invoice Grid Amount Column value has 0 . you can see there i mention in this screenshot https://screenshots.firefox.com/ePbQ97upXAt2b3Ok/localhost  
But when i click on view invoice then in detail page everything is good e.g subtotal,granttotal etc . .
Why show 0 in Invoice Grid at Amount column ?

Comment: As I said, I don't know what the 'Amount' column is - in standard Magento there are columns named 'Grand Total'  but not 'Amount' in the grid. Did you change something in the grid? Check the data in the grid table with `select * from sales_invoice_grid where increment_id = '000000039';` to see if the data in the grid table is correct.

Comment: HelgeB sorry for late response . i was on lunch break . 
I don't know why not `Grand Total` column is not in my Magento 2.2.6 Community edition.
I don't work on invoice grid.
am install an other magento for checking default behavior, there also `Amount` Column exist not `Grand Total` check screenshot of new magento install  
 https://screenshots.firefox.com/91y3JNkL4P1BX7CO/localhost

Comment: am run this query in mysql `select * from sales_invoice_grid where increment_id = '000000039';`
1 row affected and there is grand total column exist . its mean invoice correctly generated but why invoice grid `Amount` column has not correct data

Comment: OK, now I've got the view you are talking about :-) Anyway the data source is the same: the value is from `grand_total` field in `sales_invoice_grid` table. If you have a value in that field in the database that would really be strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91365/discussion-between-hafiz-umer-and-helgeb).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Inject this in your constructor

```
 \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $itemFactory
```

and add this in your constructor

```
 $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
```

then you can apply filter like this anywhere in your function and in your case it would be like

```
public function getAllItems()
{
    $current_seller_id = 5;
    $order = $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('current_seller_id', $current_seller_id);
    foreach ($order as $items) {
      echo $itemId =  $items->getItemId();
    }
}
```

this is how you can add filter by your attribute.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Dear in my requirement i don't make controller .
I have to extend this same method  `getAllItems` of this class `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice.php`
have any other way to apply filter on same class ?

Comment: Updated and you can use anywhere to apply filter in this method whether it is block or controller etc.., @HaFizUmer

Comment: @HaFizUmer make sure addFieldToFilter() is for non-EAV collection and for EAV collection you gotta go with addAttributeToFilter() and the arguments remains same.

Answer (score 0):

am Giving answer of my question after 2 days struggle, i don't want to spend time others also.

My Problem was that just display those Invoice Items in the New Invoice Page which is belong to current login admin(seller).
 1 order may contain 5 products that is belong to different sellers. I already filter items in order view page on the condition on custom attribute(`current_seller_id`) in `sales_order_item`.Now want to also filter items to invoice in new Invoice page.
i use plugin.
make di.xml in the directory `VendorName\ModuleName\etc`
**Code**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice">
        <plugin name="Invoice_collection_filterPlugin" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Invoice" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

make file `Invoice.php` in `VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Invoice.php`

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class Invoice{
protected $authSession;
public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession)
{
$this->authSession=$authSession;
}
    public function afterGetAllItems(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $subject,$items)
    {
        $filter_InvoiceItems=[];
        $CurrentUserId=$this->authSession->getUser()->getUserId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $orderitemrepo = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface');
        foreach ($items as $row)
        {
            $item_id=$row->getOrderItemId();
            $Item_recorde=$orderitemrepo->get($item_id);
            if($Item_recorde->getData('current_seller_id')==$CurrentUserId){
                $filter_InvoiceItems[]=$row;
            }
        }
        return $filter_InvoiceItems;
    }
}
```

See please 
[image]

In this order has 5 items But just display 2 because current seller has 2 product in this order.

Thank you